# how to find the viewcontroll from a segue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need to assign data source to a view controller segued by press a button in appdelegate.swift. How can I find the view controller by a segue identifier. I know I can find in a navigation controller by

```
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! ListViewController
```

like this. Is there a way to find a view controller when only the segue is connected with the previous view controller?

In other words, how to identify any vc in a project? Is storyboard ID used for this?

Comment: by press a button in appdelegate ? What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean the view controller I want to identify is connect to the previous view controller by press a button in the view controller. So I segued from the previous vc to the vc I want to identify. Maybe nothing to do with the button. I just have  a vc and segued to another vc and I want to identify this another  vc in app delegate using previous vc.

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ListViewController
```

Comment: Thanks..wait. you did't use segue identifier. Here

Comment: No this one.I don't need to present vc. Then how can I identify the segue?